# Neighborhoods of $0$ in the co-countable topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Define $\tau = \emptyset \cup \{E \subset \mathbb{R} : E^c \:\: \text{is countable}\}$. I have shown that this is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.  Now I want to show that the set of neighborhoods of $0$ does not have a countable base.

This is an old qualifier question.  I have not taken an actual topology course, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take any countable family $\{ V_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ of neighbourhoods of $0$. See that there is a neighbourhood $$W \subsetneq \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} V_n$$ of $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Daniel's comment: note that
$$
\bigcap_{n \in \Bbb N} V_n = [\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} (V_n)^c]^c
$$
and that $\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} (V_n)^c$ is the countable union of countable sets, which is therefore countable.

Now take $\bigcap_{n \in \Bbb N} V_n$, and remove a single point.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there is a countable base for the topology, $(V_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. We can assume all $V_n$ non-empty. For each $n$, pick $x_n\in V_n$. Then $C=\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a closed set, i.e. $V=\mathbb R\setminus C$ is open and non-empty. But there is no $V_n\subset U$ (since $x_n\notin U$), which is a contradiction.

Comment: One addition: to ensure that $C$ is a neighborhood of $0$, select each $x_n$ to be non-zero.